# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type Models but needs ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've been struggling with this error for a few days now for an assignment and I can't get it fixed, I've shown it to another person and we are bewildered as to what could be the issue? "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'FYP_RSVP_MGMT.Models.GuestList', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FYP_RSVP_MGMT.ViewModels.GuestListViewModel'."

**GuestListController:**

```
public class GuestListController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        GuestListViewModel guest = new GuestListViewModel();

        return View("Index", guest);
    }

    public IActionResult CreateUpdate(GuestListViewModel guest)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = DbHelpers.GetConnection()) {

                if(guest.EditableGuest.GuestID == null)
                {
                    /* Count the existing IDs and adds the next ID */
                    guest.EditableGuest.GuestID = guest.Guests.Count;

                    db.Insert<GuestList>(guest.EditableGuest);
                }

                /* If the guest already exists, we are updating the details*/
                else
                {
                    GuestList dbItem = db.Get<GuestList>(guest.EditableGuest.GuestID);

                    TryUpdateModelAsync<GuestList>(dbItem, "EditableGuest");

                    db.Update<GuestList>(dbItem);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ViewGuestList");
        }

        else
        {
            return View("Index", new GuestList());
        }
       
    }
```

**GuestListViewModel**

```
public class GuestListViewModel
{
    public GuestListViewModel()
    {
        using (var db = DbHelpers.GetConnection())
        {
            this.EditableGuest = new GuestList();

            this.Guests = db.Query<GuestList>("Select * From GuestList").ToList();
        }
    }

    public List <GuestList> Guests { get; set; }

    /* Holds any instance of an object that is being added/edited/deleted etc */
    public GuestList EditableGuest { get; set; }


}
```

**GuestList Model**

```
 public class GuestList
{
    public int? GuestID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuestName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuestType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ContactDetails { get; set; }

    public bool PlusOne { get; set; }

    public string PlusOneName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml - where form is being displayed

```
@model FYP_RSVP_MGMT.ViewModels.GuestListViewModel

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Guest RSVP";
 }

    @using (var form = Html.BeginForm("CreateUpdate", "GuestList", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<div class="container" id="GuestRSVP">

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <h3> Welcome to [Bride] and [Groom]s Wedding</h3>
    <h4>[Church Location]</h4>
    <h4>[Wedding Date and Time]</h4>

    <div class="container"  id="RSVPTable" style="align-content:center">

        <table>

            

            <tr>
                <td>Guest Name: </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.GuestName)</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EditableGuest.GuestID)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Guest Type: </td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EditableGuest.GuestType, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Guest", Text = "Guest" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "Wedding Party", Text = "Wedding Party" } })</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Contact Details: </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.ContactDetails)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Plus One: </td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.PlusOne)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Plus One Name: </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.PlusOneName)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>RSVP Response:</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EditableGuest.Response, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Accept with Pleasure", Text = "Accept with Pleasure" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "Decline with Regret", Text = "Decline with Regret" } })</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><button class="btnSubmitRSVP" type="submit"> @(Model.EditableGuest.GuestID > 0? "Update": "Add") </button></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </div>


</div>
```

}

We cannot figure out why the model is being passed and not the viewmodel? My code doesn't refer to the model? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `CreateUpdate` in the else clause  has `return View("Index", new GuestList());`

Comment: @GuruStron wait do you mean that I should take out the code in the else clause and replace it with return View("Index", new GuestList()); ?

Comment: I mean that in the else you already have this code in the else clause.

Comment: And it should be something like `return View("Index",new GuestListViewModel());`

Comment: @GuruStron you're right! I thought it was GuestList as in <GuestList> for some reason, not thinking that it was the Model, thanks for your help!

Comment: `/* Count the existing IDs and adds the next ID */` - definitely avoid doing this; make the GuestID an auto incrementing integer column and let the DB handle what number to dole out; don't do a `MAX(id)+1` and definitely don't do a `COUNT(*)+1` - as soon as a record is deleted a count+1 calculates colliding IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's coming from here:

[image]

You're sending a GuestList in the `else` despite promising you'd send a `GuestListViewModel` at the top of the page:

[image]

Comment: That would be it! Thank you so much! Next trouble is getting it to enter my database when you add a guest in the View!

Comment: Feel free to pose another question on it; there is no shortage of smart cookies here :)